# React redux props undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-props

I'm new to redux and I find it hard to find a good guide that both uses async calls and typescript. I've tried to figure it out myself but I'm a little bit stuck. If someone could take a look at my code and maybe give me feedback and/or suggestions as to how I can solve this I would be very grateful!

```
// types.ts file
export const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_USERS_REQUEST';
export const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USERS_FAILURE';
```

^ Here I define the constants for consistency.

```
// userActions.ts
import { FETCH_USERS_FAILURE, FETCH_USERS_REQUEST, FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS } from './types';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

export interface UserProps {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
}

export const fetchUsersRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
  };
};

export const fetchUsersSuccess = (users: Array<UserProps>) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    users: users,
  };
};

export const fetchUsersFailure = (error: string) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
    error: error,
  };
};

export const fetchUsers = () => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<unknown> => {
    dispatch(fetchUsersRequest());
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<UserProps[]>) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(response.data));
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error: string) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error));
      });
  };
};
```

userReducer

```
import { UserProps } from '../actions/userActions';
import { FETCH_USERS_FAILURE, FETCH_USERS_REQUEST, FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

interface Action {
  type: string
  payload: Array<UserProps> | string,
}

export interface initialStateProps {
  loading: boolean,
  users: Array<UserProps>
  error: string
}

const initialState: initialStateProps = {
  loading: false,
  users: [],
  error: '',
};

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: action.payload,
      };
    case FETCH_USERS_FAILURE:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export const getUsers = (state: initialStateProps) => state.users;
export const getUsersRequest = (state: initialStateProps) => state.loading;
export const getUsersFailure = (state: initialStateProps) => state.error;
```

And then for my project I use `connected-router` to help with keeping track of the routes.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { History } from 'history';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { userReducer } from './userReducers';

export const createRootReducer = (history: History) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  userReducer,
});
```

The store:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createRootReducer } from './reducers';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const configureStore = (preloadedState?: any) => {
  const composeEnhancer: typeof compose = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  return createStore(
    createRootReducer(history),
    preloadedState,
    composeEnhancer(
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history),
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware,
      ),
    ),
  );
};
```

And in the application I use this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: initialStateProps) => ({
  error: getUsersFailure(state),
  users: getUsers(state),
  loading: getUsersRequest(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  fetchUsers: fetchUsers
}, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(TopbarNav);
```

But when I `console.log(props);` I get:

`users: undefined`

`loading: undefined`

`error: undefined`

**EDIT:**
Here I run the fetchUsers:

```
const TopbarNav: React.FC = (props: any) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchUsers();
  });

  const handler = () => {
    console.log({props});
  };
};
```

I left the render method out in this question.

**EDIT 2 updated useEffect method:**

```
const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);

const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

const classes = useStyles();

useEffect(() => {
  setUsers(props.fetchUsers());
}, [users, props, loading]);

const handler = () => {
  console.log(props.loading);
};
```

Comment: Where do you run the fetchUsers()?

Comment: Inside useEffect

Comment: Your code seems fine, maybe we are missing a few things. A common approach to these kind of things is to isolate each component of your code. 
Try getting the initial state into your component, then call the redux action through the component.

Comment: Okay and how would I do that? Like can you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe try to debug through react and redux extension. check `redux extension` first to make sure that you dispatch the action and save the data into the store. Then check `react extension` to see the props of the component. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `combineReducers` that way I think your state will look like this

```
{
  router: ...,
  userReducer: ...,
}
```

so you could fix it by modifying the selectors to look for the correct props

```
state.userReducer.users
state.userReducer.loading
...
```

Comment: This does work, but it endlessly keeps executing in the useEffect method even though I supply an array with props and users to the method.

Comment: @Ezrab_ those changes don't look too good, you don't need local states for users and loading since you already have them in props, try undoing that, call just props.fetchUsers() in useEffect, pass an empry array as dependencies since it does not depends on any prop and wrap the component in React.memo, wherever you need users or loading use them from props: props.user, props.loading

Comment: Could you briefly explain why wrapping the component in React.memo would be a logical option?

Comment: @Ezrab_ I thought it would be necessary because you were having problems with useEffect executing every render, but if you got it working without it it's ok I guess